# Brain teaser: How to generate 7 integers with equal probability using a biased coin that has a pr(head) = p?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, random-generation

This is a question I found on [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Microsoft-Data-Scientist-Interview-Questions-EI_IE1651.0,9_KO10,24_IP4.htm): How does one generate 7 integers with equal probability using a coin that has a $\mathbb{Pr}(\text{Head}) = p\in(0,1)$?

Basically, you have a coin that may or may not be fair, and this is the only random-number generating process you have, so come up with random number generator that outputs integers from 1 to 7 where the probability of getting each of these integers is 1/7.

Efficiency of the data-generates process matters.

Comment: Related, non-dupe: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256563/why-is-generating-8-random-bits-uniform-on-0-255/256566#256566

Comment: There are myriad ways to accomplish this.  A more interesting version of the question asks for the *best* method in some well-defined sense.  A natural sense of best would be *least expected number of flips per integer generated.* Another interesting version is to describe *all possible solutions* (that rely on independent flips of the coin and nothing more).

Comment: @whuber good suggestion, I've edited the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: <<<Basically, you have a coin that may or may not be fair, and this is the only random-number generating process you have>>>

Does this mean, using the coin in any different method than flipping it and checking for head vs. tail is "forbidden", since it would be another random-number generating process?

Comment: @Sycorax points out that in the extreme cases p = 0 or 1, you'll have to resort to physically using the coin in one of various ways. You might like to specify 0 < p < 1

Comment: Mod 7 of the year on the coin.

Comment: @Nat $1 + (\text{year} \mod 7)$ yields 1 through 7. Your solution yields 0 through 6.

Comment: First define $p = 0.5$...

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223196, merely with different numbers (7 and 2 instead of 10 and 6).  It is also very closely related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209106.

Answer (score 59):

Flip the coin twice. If it lands `HH` or `TT`, ignore it and flip it twice again.

Now, the coin has equal probability of coming up `HT` or `TH`. If it comes up `HT`, call this `H1`. If it comes up `TH`, call this `T1`.

Keep obtaining `H1` or `T1` until you have three in a row. These three results give you a number based on the table below:

```
H1 H1 H1 -> 1
H1 H1 T1 -> 2
H1 T1 H1 -> 3
H1 T1 T1 -> 4
T1 H1 H1 -> 5
T1 H1 T1 -> 6
T1 T1 H1 -> 7
T1 T1 T1 -> [Throw out all results so far and repeat]
```

I argue that this would work perfectly fine, although you would have a lot of wasted throws in the process!

Comment: Nice. There is just the possibility that this might go on forever, if we keep on getting `T1`. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It seems like that's a risk in any scheme where we throw out certain data. It's also possible to keep going forever if we keep flipping `H` in a random sequence. The probability of either, though, becomes vanishingly small the longer we flip

Comment: The only constraint is that the probability of heads is "p". Note that p could be $0$, or $1$. So this isn't guaranteed to work, but Sycorax's (or Sephan's) would work, even in those cases.

Comment: @gung: I'm not sure I'd work for a coin with two heads, or two tails.

Comment: With probability $1$ it will finish in finite time.

Comment: This is called Von-Neuman whitening.

Comment: In the best case of p=1, you need to throw the coin 7.5 times on average to obtain a single bit (H1 or T1). This number goes to infinity as p approaches 0 or 1. So it doesn't seem like a particularly efficient answer ;-)

Comment: @M.Herzkamp the best case is p=0.5 (instead of p=1)..... in this case the probability for a mixed sequence HT or TH is highest (2*p*(1-p)=50%). Then the mean number of coin throws to obtain a H1 or T1 bit is 4 times (how did you get to 7.5?). To complete this... since only 7/8 of the three bit sequences are successful you need on average 8/7*4*3 ~  13.7 coin throws. (a possible improvement is to accept sequences like HHTT or TTHH, by undoing the discard)

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, plus I failed to double check my hasty calculations. You are perfectly right!You need on average 1/p(1-p) throws to get a bit.

Comment: @clark, not if p=0 or p=1. I think we have to assume p in (0,1) to produce a finite time solution whatever algorithm you use, though.

Comment: You can iterate the von Neumann extractor to more fully extract entropy from the sequence. Gather all the HH and TT pairs, consider that a sequence, apply the von Neumann extractor to that, etc..

Answer (score 49):

Assume that $p \in (0,1)$.

**Step 1:**. Toss the coin 5 times.

If the outcome is

$(H, H, H, T, T)$, return $1$ and stop.

$(H, H, T, T, H)$, return $2$ and stop.

$(H, T, T, H, H)$, return $3$ and stop.

$(T, T, H, H, H)$, return $4$ and stop.

$(T, H, H, H, T)$, return $5$ and stop.

$(H, H, T, H, T)$, return $6$ and stop.

$(H, T, H, T, H)$, return $7$ and stop.

**Step 2:**. If the outcome is none of the above, repeat Step 1.

Note that regardless of the value of $p \in (0,1)$, each of the seven outcomes listed above has probability $q = p^3(1-p)^2$, and the expected number of coin tosses is $\displaystyle \frac{5}{7q}$.  The tosser doesn't need to know the value of $p$ (except that $p\neq 0$ and $p\neq 1$); it is guaranteed that the seven integers are equally likely to be returned by the experiment when it terminates (and it is guaranteed to end with probability $1$).

Comment: Just in case the tosser knows the probability they can change the flips to contain 3 H & 2 T (if p(H)>0.5) or 2 H & 3 T (if p(H)<0.5) to reduce the expected number of coin tosses. p(H)=0.5 has an even better solution

Comment: Can we reduce the expected number of tosses for this by allowing either the sequence specified here OR that sequence with each flip inverted. eg: For 1, either (H,H,H,T,T) or (T,T,T,H,H)?

Comment: You could add the complement as well. If the outcome is (H,H,H,T,T) or (T,T,T,H,H), return 1 and stop, etc. In that case the probability for each outcome is $q=p^3(1-p)^2+p^2(1-p)^3$.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings adding the symmetric counterparts actually improves the expected number of throws so that it beats NcAdams solution in the range 0.3 < p < 0.6. For larger or smaller p, however, it gets much worse pretty fast.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just add another coin-flip if the result is not withing any (H,H,H,T,T) arrangement? 
With the additional coin-toss you'd need another mapping of (H,H,H,T,T,T) and (H,H,T,T,T,T) and each xT(7-x)H combination that can be arranged in 7 or more different orders to the numbers 1 to 7.
Instead of retossing all 5 coins this would add only 1 additional toss, but im not sure if it works :D

Comment: Maybe it might be the best thing to instantly flip the coin 7 times, since than it is guaranteed, that you will get a random number out of it (only exception therefore is, that the coin lands heads up or tail up all 7 tries). 
So with 7 tosses you could end up with 1 up to 6 heads (i exclude the 0 and 7 option here since its pointless). 

If one head there are 7 different arrangements of (H,T,T,T,T,T,T) possible;
If 2 heads its 21; 
if 3 heads its 35;
if 4 35 heads;
if 5 21 heads;
if 6 7 heads; 
Each can be perfectly mapped to number 1-7 without any combination lost.

Comment: @TinglTanglBob This is essentially Martijn Weterings answer ;-)

Comment: @M.Herzkamp, yes you are absolutely right! 
I should have read and tried to understand before posting, sorry

Comment: @MartijnWeterings This enhanced scheme is probably the most efficient for an arbitrary p. It doesn't change asymptotics as p-> 0 or 1, but it requires maybe one toss less than always tossing 7 coins.

Answer (score 23):

#### Generalizing the case described by Dilip Sarwate

Some of the methods described in the other answers use a scheme in which you throw a sequence of $n$ coins in a 'turn' and depending on the result you choose a number between 1 or 7 or discard the turn and throw again.

The trick is to find in the expansion of possibilities a multiple of 7 outcomes with the same probability $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ and match those against each other.

Because the total number of outcomes is not a multiple of 7, we have a few outcomes that we can not assign to a number, and have some probability that we need to discard the outcomes and start over.

---

#### The case of using 7 coin flips per turn

Intuitively we could say that rolling the dice seven times would be very interesting. Since we only need to throw out 2 out of the $2^7$ possibilities. Namely, the 7 times heads and 0 times heads.

For all other $2^7-2$ possibilities there is always a multiple of 7 cases with the same number of heads. Namely 7 cases with 1 heads, 21 cases with 2 heads, 35 cases with 3 heads, 35 cases with 4 heads, 21 cases with 5 heads, and 7 cases with 6 heads.

So if you compute the number (discarding 0 heads and 7 heads) $$X = \sum_{k=1}^{7} (k-1) \cdot C_k $$

with $C_k$ Bernoulli distributed variables (value 0 or 1), then X modulo 7 is a uniform variable with seven possible results.

---

#### Comparing different number of coin flips per turn

The question remains what the optimal number of rolls per turn would be. Rolling more dices per turn cost you more, but you reduce the probability to have to roll again.

The image below shows a manual computations for the first few numbers of coin flips per turn. (possibly there might be an analytical solution, but I believe it is safe to say that a system with 7 coin flips provides the best method regarding the expectation value for the necessary number of coin flips)

[image: expected number of coin flips]

```r
# plot an empty canvas
plot(-100,-100,
     xlab="flips per turn",
     ylab="E(total flips)",
     ylim=c(7,400),xlim=c(0,20),log="y")
title("expectation value for total number of coin flips
(number of turns times flips per turn)")

# loop 1
# different values p from fair to very unfair 
# since this is symmetric only from 0 to 0.5 is necessary 

# loop 2
# different values for number of flips per turn
# we can only use a multiple of 7 to assign 
#   so the modulus will have to be discarded
#   from this we can calculate the probability that the turn succeeds
#   the expected number of flips is 
#       the flips per turn 
#             divided by 
#       the probability for the turn to succeed 

for (p in c(0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05)) {
  Ecoins <- rep(0,16)
  for (dr in (5:20)){
    Pdiscards = 0
    for (i in c(0:dr)) { 
      Pdiscards = Pdiscards + p^(i)*(1-p)^(dr-i) * (choose(dr,i) %% 7)
    }
    Ecoins[dr-4] = dr/(1-Pdiscards)
  }
  lines(5:20, Ecoins)
  points(5:20, Ecoins, pch=21, col="black", bg="white", cex=0.5)
  text(5, Ecoins[1], paste0("p = ",p), pos=2)
}
```

---

#### Using an early stopping rule

*note: the calculations below, for the expectation value of number of flips, are for a fair coin $p=0.5$, it would become a mess to do this for different $p$, but the principle remains the same (although different book-keeping of the cases is needed)*

We should be able to choose the cases (instead of the formula for $X$) such that we might be able to stop earlier.

- **With 5 coin flips** we have for the six possible different unordered sets of heads and tails:

  1+5+10+10+5+1 ordered sets

  And we can use the groups with ten cases (that is the group with 2 heads or the group with 2 tails) to choose (with equal probability) a number. This occurs in 14 out of 2^5=32 cases. This leaves us with:

  1+5+3+3+5+1 ordered sets
- **With an extra (6-th) coin flip** we have for the seven possible different unordered sets of heads and tails:

  1+6+8+6+8+6+1 ordered sets

  And we can use the groups with eight cases (that is the group with 3 heads or the group with 3 tails) to choose (with equal probability) a number. This occurs in 14 out of 2*(2^5-14)=36 cases. This leaves us with:

  1+6+1+6+1+6+1 ordered sets
- **With another (7-th) extra coin flip** we have for the eight possible different unordered sets of heads and tails:

  1+7+7+7+7+7+7+1 ordered sets

  And we can use the groups with seven cases (all except the all tails and all heads cases) to choose (with equal probability) a number. This occurs in 42 out of 44 cases. This leaves us with:

  1+0+0+0+0+0+0+1 ordered sets

  (we could continue this but only in the 49-th step does this give us an advantage)

So the probability to select a number

- at 5 flips is $\frac{14}{32} = \frac{7}{16}$
- at 6 flips is $\frac{9}{16}\frac{14}{36} = \frac{7}{32}$
- at 7 flips is $\frac{11}{32}\frac{42}{44} = \frac{231}{704}$
- not in 7 flips is $1-\frac{7}{16}-\frac{7}{32}-\frac{231}{704} = \frac{2}{2^7}$

This makes the expectation value for the number of flips in one turn, conditional that there is success and p=0.5:

$$5 \cdot \frac{7}{16}+ 6 \cdot \frac{7}{32} + 7 \cdot \frac{231}{704} = 5.796875 $$

The expectation value for the *total* number of flips (until there is a success), conditional that p=0.5, becomes:

$$\left(5 \cdot \frac{7}{16}+ 6 \cdot \frac{7}{32} + 7  \cdot \frac{231}{704}\right) \frac{2^7}{2^7-2} = \frac{53}{9} = 5.88889 $$

---

The answer by NcAdams uses a variation of this stopping-rule strategy (each time come up with two new coin flips) but is not optimally selecting out all the flips.

The answer by Clid might be similar as well although there might be an uneven selection rule that each two coin flips a number might be chosen but not necessarily with equal probability (a discrepancy which is being repaired during later coin flips)

---

#### Comparison with other methods

Other methods using a similar principle are the one by NcAdams and AdamO.

**The principle is**: A decision for a number between 1 and 7 is made after a certain number of heads and tails. After an $x$ number of flips, for each decision that leads to a number $i$ there is a similar, equally probable, decision that leads to a number $j$ (the same number of heads and tails but just in a different order). Some series of heads and tails can lead to a decision to start over.

For such type of methods the one placed here is the most efficient because it makes the decisions as early as possible (as soon as there is a possibility for 7 equal probability sequences of heads and tails, after the $x$-th flip, we can use them to make a decision on a number and we do not need to flip further if we encounter one of those cases).

This is demonstrated by the image and simulation below:

[image: comparison]

```r
#### mathematical part #####
set.seed(1)


#plotting this method
p <- seq(0.001,0.999,0.001)
tot <- (5*7*(p^2*(1-p)^3+p^3*(1-p)^2)+
       6*7*(p^2*(1-p)^4+p^4*(1-p)^2)+
       7*7*(p^1*(1-p)^6+p^2*(1-p)^5+p^3*(1-p)^4+p^4*(1-p)^3+p^5*(1-p)^2+p^6*(1-p)^1)+
        7*1*(0+p^7+(1-p)^7) )/
             (1-p^7-(1-p)^7)
plot(p,tot,type="l",log="y",
     xlab="p",
     ylab="expactation value number of flips"
     )

#plotting method by AdamO
tot <- (7*(p^20-20*p^19+189*p^18-1121*p^17+4674*p^16-14536*p^15+34900*p^14-66014*p^13+99426*p^12-119573*p^11+114257*p^10-85514*p^9+48750*p^8-20100*p^7+5400*p^6-720*p^5)+6*
          (-7*p^21+140*p^20-1323*p^19+7847*p^18-32718*p^17+101752*p^16-244307*p^15+462196*p^14-696612*p^13+839468*p^12-806260*p^11+610617*p^10-357343*p^9+156100*p^8-47950*p^7+9240*p^6-840*p^5)+5*
          (21*p^22-420*p^21+3969*p^20-23541*p^19+98154*p^18-305277*p^17+733257*p^16-1389066*p^15+2100987*p^14-2552529*p^13+2493624*p^12-1952475*p^11+1215900*p^10-594216*p^9+222600*p^8-61068*p^7+11088*p^6-1008*p^5)+4*(-
          35*p^23+700*p^22-6615*p^21+39235*p^20-163625*p^19+509425*p^18-1227345*p^17+2341955*p^16-3595725*p^15+4493195*p^14-4609675*p^13+3907820*p^12-2745610*p^11+1592640*p^10-750855*p^9+278250*p^8-76335*p^7+13860*p^6-
          1260*p^5)+3*(35*p^24-700*p^23+6615*p^22-39270*p^21+164325*p^20-515935*p^19+1264725*p^18-2490320*p^17+4027555*p^16-5447470*p^15+6245645*p^14-6113275*p^13+5102720*p^12-3597370*p^11+2105880*p^10-999180*p^9+371000
           *p^8-101780*p^7+18480*p^6-1680*p^5)+2*(-21*p^25+420*p^24-3990*p^23+24024*p^22-103362*p^21+340221*p^20-896679*p^19+1954827*p^18-3604755*p^17+5695179*p^16-7742301*p^15+9038379*p^14-9009357*p^13+7608720*p^12-
           5390385*p^11+3158820*p^10-1498770*p^9+556500*p^8-152670*p^7+27720*p^6-2520*p^5))/(7*p^27-147*p^26+1505*p^25-10073*p^24+49777*p^23-193781*p^22+616532*p^21-1636082*p^20+3660762*p^19-6946380*p^18+11213888*p^17-
           15426950*p^16+18087244*p^15-18037012*p^14+15224160*p^13-10781610*p^12+6317640*p^11-2997540*p^10+1113000*p^9-305340*p^8+55440*p^7-5040*p^6)
lines(p,tot,col=2,lty=2)

#plotting method by NcAdam
lines(p,3*8/7/(p*(1-p)),col=3,lty=2)

legend(0.2,500,
       c("this method calculation","AdamO","NcAdams","this method simulation"),
       lty=c(1,2,2,0),pch=c(NA,NA,NA,1),col=c(1,2,3,1))


##### simulation part ######

#creating decision table
mat<-matrix(as.numeric(intToBits(c(0:(2^5-1)))),2^5,byrow=1)[,c(1:12)]
colnames(mat) <- c("b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","b6","b7","sum5","sum6","sum7","decision","exit")

# first 5 rolls
mat[,8] <- sapply(c(1:2^5), FUN = function(x) {sum(mat[x,1:5])})

mat[which((mat[,8]==2)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],12] = rep(5,7) # we can stop for 7 cases with 2 heads
mat[which((mat[,8]==2)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],11] = c(1:7)   
mat[which((mat[,8]==3)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],12] = rep(5,7) # we can stop for 7 cases with 3 heads
mat[which((mat[,8]==3)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],11] = c(1:7)    

# extra 6th roll
mat <- rbind(mat,mat)
mat[c(33:64),6] <- rep(1,32)
mat[,9] <- sapply(c(1:2^6), FUN = function(x) {sum(mat[x,1:6])})

mat[which((mat[,9]==2)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],12] = rep(6,7) # we can stop for 7 cases with 2 heads
mat[which((mat[,9]==2)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],11] = c(1:7)   
mat[which((mat[,9]==4)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],12] = rep(6,7) # we can stop for 7 cases with 4 heads
mat[which((mat[,9]==4)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],11] = c(1:7)    

# extra 7th roll
mat <- rbind(mat,mat)
mat[c(65:128),7] <- rep(1,64)
mat[,10] <- sapply(c(1:2^7), FUN = function(x) {sum(mat[x,1:7])})

for (i in 1:6) {
  mat[which((mat[,10]==i)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],12] = rep(7,7) # we can stop for 7 cases with i heads
  mat[which((mat[,10]==i)&(mat[,11]==0))[1:7],11] = c(1:7)   
}


mat[1,12] = 7           # when we did not have succes we still need to count the 7 coin tosses
mat[2^7,12] = 7


draws = rep(0,100)
num = rep(0,100)
# plotting simulation
for (p in seq(0.05,0.95,0.05)) {
  n <- rep(0,1000)
  for (i in 1:1000) {
    coinflips <- rbinom(7,1,p)  # draw seven numbers
    I <- mat[,1:7]-matrix(rep(coinflips,2^7),2^7,byrow=1) == rep(0,7)                      # compare with the table
    Imatch = I[,1]*I[,2]*I[,3]*I[,4]*I[,5]*I[,6]*I[,7]        # compare with the table 
      draws[i] <- mat[which(Imatch==1),11]                 # result which number
      num[i]   <- mat[which(Imatch==1),12]                 # result how long it took
  }
  Nturn <- mean(num)                   #how many flips we made
  Sturn <- (1000-sum(draws==0))/1000   #how many numbers we got (relatively)
  points(p,Nturn/Sturn)
}
```

another image which is scaled by $p*(1-p)$ for better comparison:

[image: comparison with scaled expectation values]

zoom in comparing methods described in this post and comments

[image: comparison methods described here]

the 'conditional skipping of the 7-th step' is a slight improvement which can be made on the early stopping rule. In this case you select not groups with equal probabilities after the 6-th flips. You have 6 groups with equal probabilities, and 1 groups with a slightly different probability (for this last group you need to flip one more extra time when you have 6 heads or tails and because you discard the 7 heads or 7 tails, you will end up with the same probability after all)

Comment: I was just about starting to make the calculations for the n=7 case, because I had a feeling it might be better than n=1. Have my upvote, sir!

Comment: @M.Herzkamp a small improvement is still possible. One number $C_k$ (one coin flip) is not necessary for the calculation of $X$, because it has coefficient 0. This number is only necessary to determine the case of all heads or all tails, and it can be omitted when we already know that we have a mixed case.

Comment: So the improvement brings it down to a bit more than 6 coin flips as expectation value for the number of required coin flips. It would be vary though to *proof* that this is the optimal solution. The scheme created by Clid diverges a bit allowing to choose a number at a particular number of coin flips but *not* with equal probability (at least not for that particular step, it will be corrected later).

Comment: But if you're deciding whether to flip the sixth coin based on the first five results, are the probabilities of each set, conditioned on you got to six flips, the same as for the other sets?

Comment: @Acccumulation you could draw it as a binary  tree with 7 levels. We will only be selecting among nodes if there are 7 with equal probability. It is like you chop of some branches earlier (at level 5 or 6). If you like then you could continue untill 7 steps, instead of earlier, but for these particular cases the 6th and 7th coin flip do not make a difference.

Comment: @Accumulation: You definitely need to be careful in designing your mapping scheme from outcomes to the resulting numbers. For instance, if you have a 5-coin pattern which allows you to stop immediately with "3", any 7-coin pattern that could arise from this 5-coin start also should have "3" as a result.

Comment: Maybe as another little (very tiny) improvement that wont reduce the number of tosses but the number of <H-T-combination to number mapping evaluations>:
If you end up with 5 H or 5 T after 5 tosses you could skip the post toss 6 evaluation and just continue with another toss since max 1H (or 1T) out of 6 wont allowe you to finde numbers. 
For a computer-coin-tosser this improvement might not be noticeable at all, but for a human tosser i think the looking-up the mapping-table step is the one that takes time :)

Comment: @TinglTanglBob, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Martijn Weterings, i'll try to explain it a bit better (sorry for the bad english).
I think the algorythmus of generating a number would be something like this: Step1: Flipe coin 5 times; Step2: Find random Number for archieved H-T-combination from mapping-Table - if found, abort here and return number; Step3: flip coin once and add the result to the 5 previous flips; Step4: same as Step2 but now use the 6-flips Table; Step 7: flip coin once and add to the previous 6 flips; Step8: Look up Number for archieved combination in the 7-flips Table.

Comment: If Step 1 brings 5 H or 5 T, we can be sure, that after 6 flips there wont be a number fitting the archieved H-T-combination too. 
So in this case we could just proceed with Step 5 after Step3 and skip Step 4. And sorry for my bad counting too. In previous post Step 7 should be Step 5 and step 8 Step 6

Comment: @TinglTanglBob, do you mean that after 5H or 5T in the 5th flip, we can directly flip an extra two times instead of an extra single time?

Comment: yes! thats what i wanted to say

Comment: @TinglTanglBob, if you want simplicity you use the first method, flipping seven coins and calculate $X$ according to the simple formula. Note that one of the coefficients is zero so you do not really have to flip this 7th coin unless all the others ended up 6H or 6T. With this simpler method you get already very close to the optimal case.

Answer (score 21):

Divide a box into seven equal-area regions, each labeled with an integer. Throw the coin into the box in such a way that it has equal probability of landing in each region.

This is only half in jest -- it's essentially the same procedure as estimating $\pi$ using a physical Monte Carlo procedure, like dropping rice grains onto paper with a circle drawn on it.

This is one of the only answer that works for the case of $p = 1$ or $p=0$.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to divide the box into seven equal-area regions, to minimize bias from flipping, bouncing off walls etc? Seven sectors of angle 360/7 ?

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a box. It could be a pie pan, or a coaster. The physical object is not important. You could use a chess board, if you appropriately allocate each square (perhaps including some "ignore" squares).

Comment: I know that. Since you suggested a box, I was pointing out the bias added from wherever you flip the coin, and also bouncing off walls.

Comment: @smci That's why I stipulate that you must throw the coin so that there is uniform probability of it landing in each square. If bouncing off of a wall influences that probability, then you have to account for it in your throw.

Comment: Yes I know that, and I'm pointing out to *you* that simply saying *"throw it in an unbiased way"* without defining exactly how to achieve that, is not really a full answer... in which case the flipping-H/T based methods are superior.

Comment: @smci I think it's worth noting that the flip-based methods implicitly assume that $p\neq0$ and $p\neq1$. There's no reason this must be true, and all flip-based methods will fail when either is true.

Comment: "Equal areas, with throws that have equal probability of landing in each region" might be difficult to establish in practice. In practice it might be easier to mark out a large number of "practice runs" and then subdivide the landing area into equiprobable spaces empirically (eg with 700 throws, rule off a line that cuts off the furthest 100 throws, then another for the next 100 and so on). A simplification of this to generate a single random bit would be to throw the coin twice - if the first throw goes further, the bit is `0`, and if the second throw goes further it's a `1`

Comment: There's a nice answer by @TheScienceBoy that sadly is deleted with an interesting alternative to this - effectively, using the coin as a spinner, and marking 7 sections along its circumference - that retains much of the spirit of this answer but may be more physically straightforward to carry out!

Comment: @smci I've noticed that all of the coin flip-based answers are likewise not concerned with mechanics. For example, what if the coin hits a table edge? Does that "interference" change the outcome, or alter the of achieving a particular integer during that flip? What if the coin lands on an edge? What if by flipping teh coin we enter the darkest timeline? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remedial_Chaos_Theory

Comment: "Divide a box into seven equal-area regions, each labeled with an integer." If we can not assume that this is a fair coin in therms of heads/tails being 50-50, can we assume that it is fair when landing in regions of a box?

Comment: Seems like there's no need to account for bias in a 1-shot experiment like this.  Incidental bias introduced by accident in the 7-way-divider would be on-par with incidental bias introduced by someone flipping the coin.  I mean, an honest flipper might put enough force into it and move their hand such that they _personally_ can't predict what outcome they've selected, but they've selected the outcome nonetheless.  Likewise, the outcome of the 7-way-divide will be decided by the combination of its construction and the toss, but so long as the experimenter can't select, it's fair.

Comment: @Silverfish, Sycorax: Note that marking equiprobable 7 sections along the coin's circumference can equally be non-trivial, if the reason for the bias is the centre-of-mass is off-center (non-uniform mass distribution/thickness, varying density, heavier metal disc off-center in lighter, etc.). And in the extreme case some values could be infinitesimally close => measurement uncertainty. (TheScienceBoy's answer should not have been deleted and should be undeleted)

Comment: @smci - you could alter the spinner mechanism to one where you mark a point on the ground and drop the coin out of an airplane.  Whichever section is closest to the point gives you the number.

Comment: Sycorax: the difference is the coin-flipping answers do not need to be concerned with mechanics, since **we are given the probability p = pr(head) for flipping**. But not for rolling, or other physical methods. As to rare or near-impossible events like hitting table or landing on edge, we can ignore those and it doesn't affect p. That's implicit in what we've been told. But only for flipping.

Comment: **You don't need a box.**  Draw seven points on a reasonably flat board, each at least one coin diameter from its nearest neighbor.  Number them arbitrarily 1 through 7.  One trial consists of tossing the coin in any repeatable fashion until it first completely hides one of the points: its label is declared the outcome.  For the next trial, *cyclically relabel the points:* 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 3, ..., and 7 becomes 1.  This guarantees a uniform distribution of random outcomes (but not necessarily *independence* of the process!).  It should be obvious how to make this efficient.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: based on others' feedback.

Here's an interesting thought:

set the list of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. Throw the coin for each element in the list sequentially. If it lands head side up for a particular element, remove the number from the list. If all the numbers from a particular iteration of the list are removed, repeat the sampling. Do so until only one number remains.

```
drop.one <- function(x, p) {
  drop <- runif(length(x)) < p
  if (all(drop))
    return(x)
  return(x[!drop])
}

sample.recur <- function(x, p) {
  if (length(x) > 1)
    return(sample.recur(drop.one(x, p), p))
  return(x)
}

# x <- c(1:7,7:1)
x <- 1:7
p <- 0.01

out <- replicate(1e5, sample.recur(x, p))

round(prop.table(table(out)), 2)
```

gives me an approximately uniform distribution

```
> round(prop.table(table(out)), 2)
out
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
0.14 0.14 0.15 0.14 0.14 0.14 0.14
```

It's interesting to note (if I haven't made a dire mistake) that this produces a different result than generating $N$ binomial outcomes as the sum of 13 tosses of the coin (counting 0 heads as an outcome) and mapping the {0,1,2,...,12,13} index onto the earlier list of {1,2,3,...,3,2,1}. I don't quite know how to prove that my method works.

---

### Evaluation of expectation value for number of coin throws

The expectation value for the number coin throws can be calculated using the transition matrix below (answering the question when we start with $x$ non-eliminated numbers then what is the probability to get to $y$ non-eliminated numbers)

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
q^7       & 0                     & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\   
7p^1q^6   & q^6                   & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
21p^2q^5  & 6p^1q^5               & q^5  & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0\\   
35 p^3q^4 & 15 p^2q^4  & 5q^4  & q^4    & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0\\   
35 p^4q^3 & 20 p^3q^3  & 10 p^2q^3  & 4 p^1q^3    & q^3  & 0 & 0 & 0\\   
21p^5q^2  & 15 p^4q^2  & 10 p^3q^2  & 6 p^2q^2    & 3 p^1q^2  & q^2  & 0 & 0\\   
7p^6q^1   & 6 p^5q^1  & 5 p^4q^1  & 4 p^3q^1    & 3p^2q^1  & 2p^1q^1  & 0 & 0\\   
p^7       & p^6  & p^5  & p^4 &  p^3  & p^2  & 0  & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue 1 (which can be found by solving $(M-I)v=0$) depicts how much time is relatively spend in what state. Then 7th state is how often you will be able to draw a number from 1 to 7. The other states tell how many coin flips it costs.

Below is the image which compares with the answer from NcAdams which has expectation value for coin throws being $E(n) = \frac{24}{7}p(1-p)$

[image: comparison of expectation value for coin flips]

Remarkable is that the method performs better roughly for $p>2/3$. But also the performance is non-symmetric. A symmetric and better overall performance could be made when a probabilistic switching rule would be made which changes the decision rule from tails to heads when heads happens to be improbable.

#### Solution found with wxMaxima

```R
M: matrix(
 [(1-p)^7,        0,          0,0,0,0,1,1], 
 [7* p*(1-p)^6,   (1-p)^6,        0,0,0,0,0,0], 
 [21*p^2*(1-p)^5, 6*p*(1-p)^5,    (1-p)^5,0,0,0,0,0], 
 [35*p^3*(1-p)^4, 15*p^2*(1-p)^4, 5*p*(1-p)^4,(1-p)^4,0,0,0,0], 
 [35*p^4*(1-p)^3, 20*p^3*(1-p)^3, 10*p^2*(1-p)^3,4*p*(1-p)^3,(1-p)^3,0,0,0], 
 [21*p^5*(1-p)^2, 15*p^4*(1-p)^2, 10*p^3*(1-p)^2,6*p^2*(1-p)^2,3*p*(1-p)^2,(1-p)^2,0,0], 
 [7* p^6*(1-p)^1, 6*p^5*(1-p),    5*p^4*(1-p),4*p^3*(1-p),3*p^2*(1-p),2*(1-p)*p,0,0], 
 [p^7,        p^6,        p^5,p^4,p^3,p^2,0,0]
);
z: nullspace(M-diagmatrix(8,1));
x : apply (addcol, args (z));
t : [7,6,5,4,3,2,0,0];
plot2d(t.x/x[7],[p,0,1],logy);
```

#### Calculations in R

```R
# plotting empty canvas
plot(-100,-100,
     xlab="p",
     ylab="E(total flips)",
     ylim=c(10,1000),xlim=c(0,1),log="y")

# plotting simulation
for (p in seq(0.1,0.9,0.05)) {

  n <- rep(0,10000)
  for (i in 1:10000) {
    success  = 0
    tests = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)     # start with seven numbers in the set
    count = 0
    while(success==0) {
      for (j in 1:7)  {
        if (tests[j]==1) {
          count = count + 1
          if  (rbinom(1,1,p) == 1) {
            tests[j] <- 0        # elliminate number when we draw heads
          }
        }
      }
      if (sum(tests)==1) {
        n[i] = count
        success = 1              # end     when 1 is left over
      }
      if (sum(tests)==0) {
        tests = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) # restart when 0 are left over
      }
    }
  }
  points(p,mean(n))
}

# plotting formula
p <- seq(0.001,0.999,0.001)

tot <- (7*(p^20-20*p^19+189*p^18-1121*p^17+4674*p^16-14536*p^15+34900*p^14-66014*p^13+99426*p^12-119573*p^11+114257*p^10-85514*p^9+48750*p^8-20100*p^7+5400*p^6-720*p^5)+6*
    (-7*p^21+140*p^20-1323*p^19+7847*p^18-32718*p^17+101752*p^16-244307*p^15+462196*p^14-696612*p^13+839468*p^12-806260*p^11+610617*p^10-357343*p^9+156100*p^8-47950*p^7+9240*p^6-840*p^5)+5*
    (21*p^22-420*p^21+3969*p^20-23541*p^19+98154*p^18-305277*p^17+733257*p^16-1389066*p^15+2100987*p^14-2552529*p^13+2493624*p^12-1952475*p^11+1215900*p^10-594216*p^9+222600*p^8-61068*p^7+11088*p^6-1008*p^5)+4*(-
    35*p^23+700*p^22-6615*p^21+39235*p^20-163625*p^19+509425*p^18-1227345*p^17+2341955*p^16-3595725*p^15+4493195*p^14-4609675*p^13+3907820*p^12-2745610*p^11+1592640*p^10-750855*p^9+278250*p^8-76335*p^7+13860*p^6-
    1260*p^5)+3*(35*p^24-700*p^23+6615*p^22-39270*p^21+164325*p^20-515935*p^19+1264725*p^18-2490320*p^17+4027555*p^16-5447470*p^15+6245645*p^14-6113275*p^13+5102720*p^12-3597370*p^11+2105880*p^10-999180*p^9+371000
   *p^8-101780*p^7+18480*p^6-1680*p^5)+2*(-21*p^25+420*p^24-3990*p^23+24024*p^22-103362*p^21+340221*p^20-896679*p^19+1954827*p^18-3604755*p^17+5695179*p^16-7742301*p^15+9038379*p^14-9009357*p^13+7608720*p^12-
 5390385*p^11+3158820*p^10-1498770*p^9+556500*p^8-152670*p^7+27720*p^6-2520*p^5))/(7*p^27-147*p^26+1505*p^25-10073*p^24+49777*p^23-193781*p^22+616532*p^21-1636082*p^20+3660762*p^19-6946380*p^18+11213888*p^17-
  15426950*p^16+18087244*p^15-18037012*p^14+15224160*p^13-10781610*p^12+6317640*p^11-2997540*p^10+1113000*p^9-305340*p^8+55440*p^7-5040*p^6)
lines(p,tot)

#plotting comparison with alternative method
lines(p,3*8/7/(p*(1-p)),lty=2)

legend(0.2,500,
       c("simulation","calculation","comparison"),
       lty=c(0,1,2),pch=c(1,NA,NA))
```

Comment: Clever idea (+1).  Intuitively, it should work, since the symmetry would appear to nullify bias towards any particular number.  Still, I'd love to see a proof.

Comment: This idea is really nice, but with a high probability for head (knock out that number) i think the last number in the row hast the best chances to "survive" since all the others infront get kicked out very likely before on run 1? 

Maybe it could be changed by not sequentially throwing the coin but parallel for all the numbers in x? Runtime of the script might increase i guess :)

Comment: I agree with @TinglTanglBob - when I set `p <- 0.99` I get the output `0.89 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02`

Comment: Wouldn't performing the elimination in 'rounds' fix the bias problem? Start with 7 numbers. Toss the coin for every remaining number, and eliminate the ones that throw head. If all the remaining numbers are eliminated in a round, scratch the results of that round and try again. I don't know how to prove it, but intuitively the order of the numbers no-longer matters in whether they are the 'winner'

Comment: @TinglTanglBob thanks for pointing that out. I played with the script a bit more and my proposed solution is: use the side with less probability to be the elimination criterion. Setting $p = 0.01$ strangely fixes the problem. I echo the desire for one better than I to offer some proof for/against this "solution".

Comment: @phil ya seems good. Makes me wonder if it's even necessary to duplicate the list as I've done.

Comment: How about just using the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and redo any round in which *all* elements are removed? Then there's no bias from the ordering.

Comment: @CliffAB this requires one to repeat until *exactly* 1 number is left. That is relatively costly.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I am curious if it really results in that many more flips. The most upvoted solution requires discordant flip dyads which is also costly.

Comment: @AdamO, this adjusted answer follows the model of a binary tree where some nodes end in a decision (either we can choose a number when exactly one number is left, or we have to start over when all numbers got eliminated). But the end nodes are not at all placed as efficient as possible (one should be able to make decisions earlier). In the case of p=.5 the most efficient binary tree decision model would do *on average* a bit more than 6 coin flips. This method needs at least 7 coin flips.

Comment: @AdamO I have edited your answer by adding the calculation for expected number of coin throws in order to obtain a number between 1 to 7. It was too big of a calculation too place in the comment and I also believe it is useful for your answer. I hope you accept it.

Comment: Regarding my suggestion to flip the decision rule (heads vs tails) depending on whether we observe more heads or more tails, this improves simulations on the left side of the graph making the method better for p<0.2 as well (the difference is because it requires one round of seven unsuccessful flips before we can decide, if we do not want to be biased).

Answer (score 6):

The question is a bit ambiguous, is it asking "generate a random integer equal or less than 7 with equal probability", or is it asking "generate 7 random integers with equal probability?" - but what is the space of integers?!?

I'll assume it's the former, but the same logic I'm applying can be extended to the latter case too, once that problem is cleared up.

With a biased coin, you can produce a fair coin by following the following procedure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin

A number 7 or less can be written in binary as three {0,1} digits. So all one needs to do is follow the above procedure three times, and convert the binary number produced back to decimal.

Comment: comparing my answer with @NcAdams, it's clear I'm including 0 as a possible desirable outcome!

Comment: I don't get how your answer is different. If you include {0,0,0} -> 1 then what does {1,1,1} map to? There are 8 possibilities.

Comment: 000 maps to 0, hence my comment on including 0 as a possible value. This was posted before the OP edit and almost simultaneously as NcAdams.

Comment: Half of this answer is a comment, and the actual content of the answer is link-only. Please spell out your actual answer rather than just linking to it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in earlier comments, this puzzle relates to John von Neumann's 1951 [paper](https://mcnp.lanl.gov/pdf_files/nbs_vonneumann.pdf) "Various Techniques Used in Connection With Random Digits" published in the research journal of the National Bureau of Standards:

[image]

There is a wider literature about such problems that goes under the name of [Bernoulli factory](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=175007.175019) problems, that is, given a coin with tail probability $p$, how to simulate a coin with tail probability $f(p)$. If feasible, since some functions $f$ [cannot be](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20140423114012151-153980.pdf) used as for instance $f(p)=\min\{1,2p\}$. [Nacu and Peres (2005)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1106922322) study fast algorithms for solving [solvable] Bernoulli factory problems where fast means exponential decay of the tail of the distribution of the number $N$ of trials.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that *never* wastes flips, which helps a lot for very-biased coins.

The disadvantage of this algorithm (as written, at least) is that it's using arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Practically, you probably want to use this until integer overflow, and only then throw it away and start over.

Also, you need to know what the bias *is* ... which you might not, say, if it is temperature-dependent like most physical phenomena.

---

Assuming the chance of heads is, say, 30%.

- Start with the range `[1, 8)`.
- Flip your coin. If heads, use the left 30%, so your new range is `[1, 3.1)`. Else, use the right 70%, so your new range is `[3.1, 8)`.
- Repeat until the entire range has the same integer part.

---

Full code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from fractions import Fraction
from collections import Counter
from random import randrange


BIAS = Fraction(3, 10)
STAT_COUNT = 100000


calls = 0
def biased_rand():
    global calls
    calls += 1
    return randrange(BIAS.denominator) < BIAS.numerator


def can_generate_multiple(start, stop):
    if stop.denominator == 1:
        # half-open range
        stop = stop.numerator - 1
    else:
        stop = int(stop)
    start = int(start)
    return start != stop


def unbiased_rand(start, stop):
    if start < 0:
        # negative numbers round wrong
        return start + unbiased_rand(0, stop - start)
    assert isinstance(start, int) and start >= 0
    assert isinstance(stop, int) and stop >= start
    start = Fraction(start)
    stop = Fraction(stop)
    while can_generate_multiple(start, stop):
        if biased_rand():
            old_diff = stop - start
            diff = old_diff * BIAS
            stop = start + diff
        else:
            old_diff = stop - start
            diff = old_diff * (1 - BIAS)
            start = stop - diff
    return int(start)


def stats(f, *args, **kwargs):
    c = Counter()
    for _ in range(STAT_COUNT):
        c[f(*args, **kwargs)] += 1

    print('stats for %s:' % f.__qualname__)
    for k, v in sorted(c.items()):
        percent = v * 100 / STAT_COUNT
        print('  %s: %f%%' % (k, percent))


def main():
    #stats(biased_rand)
    stats(unbiased_rand, 1, 7+1)
    print('used %f calls at bias %s' % (calls/STAT_COUNT, BIAS))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can improve this process. Start the from the interval [0,1]; you can see your sequence of coin tosses as an infinite process that generates a single random number in $[0,1]$, uniformly. This random number has a unique base-7 expansion (apart from a probability-0 set where you have two expansions, one ending in $0000\dots$ and one in $6666\dots$). When the interval is narrow enough that you can determine its $k$th (base-7) digit uniquely, you output it. It's a while since I read about that, but if I remember correctly, this generates digits at the optimal rate by Shannon's entropy bound.

Comment: That's the same for a single output, right? Just better for multiple? I'd write it as `diff *= 7` I think ... in fact, there's no particular need to use the same base for each attempt.

Comment: Yes, it's the same if you want a single output; it only improves efficiency if you want multiple ones.

Comment: +1 This is in the spirit of the arithmetic coding procedure.And if $p$ is given as a rational number, this could be easily implemented exactly, with (unbounded) integer arithmetic. But, of course, ir requires to know $p$.

Comment: This absolutely does waste flips if you want a single output.  For a fair coin, the standard technique (roll the coin three times, and repeat if you get TTT) gives an expected number of 24/7 = 3+3/7 rolls. If you use this arithmetic-coding-style technique, you roll at least four times unless you get HHH or TTT, which gives you an expected number of more than 15/4 = 3+3/4 rolls.

Comment: @PeterShor, with a fair coin the expected number of rolls for this technique is 4.5 (once the regions got smaller than 1 width after 3 rolls, there are still always 6 cases of rolls that cover the boundaries and do not give you an answer). The calculation is demonstrated in a comment to the answer from clid, which is basically a special case ($p=0.5$) of this answer. Indeed, the question should not be about "wasting" flips but about how quickly we get, on average to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This also only works for $p \neq 1$ and $p \neq 0$.

We first turn the (possibly) unfair coin into a fair coin using the process from [NcAdams answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35468):

> Flip the coin twice. If it lands `HH` or `TT`, ignore it and flip it twice again.
>
> Now, the coin has equal probability of coming up `HT` or `TH`. If it comes up `HT`, call this `H1`. If it comes up `TH`, call this `T1`.

Now we use the fair coin to generate a real number between $0$ and $1$ in binary. Let `H1`$= 1$ and `T1` $= 0$. Start with the string `0.`, flip the coin and append the resulting digit to the at the end of the string. Repeat with the new string. For example, the sequence `H1 H1 T1` would give you the number $0.110$.

$1/7$ is a repeating decimal, and with the right-hand side being in base 2 we have that:

$1/7 = 0.001 001 001 ...$

$2/7 = 0.010 010 010 ...$

$3/7 = 0.011 011 011 ...$

$4/7 = 0.100 100 100 ...$

$5/7 = 0.101 101 101 ...$

$6/7 = 0.110 110 110 ...$

Keep flipping the fair coin to generate the decimal digits until the digits of your sequence does not match one of the above sequences, then chose the number $n$ such that your generated number is less than $n/7$ and greater than $(n-1)/7$. Since each generated number is equally likely we have chosen a number between $1$ and $7$ with equal probability.

Comment: Ignoring that this method requires a lot of flips, it is interesting how the separation of the bits into 7 equally likely parts are generated. These parts are really equally likely? For instance the $\leq 1/7$ number turns up when you flip 0.000 or when your not flipping of 0.001001001 ends up on the wrong side, which is 1/8+1/16 of the cases, or do I see this wrong?

Comment: Correction on the probability to flip $\leq 1/7$ that last number is not 1/16. So you flip 000 or 001000 or 001001000, etc which has probability $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1/8)^k = \frac{1}{7}$

Comment: So the probability for termination within $n$ bits is $T(n) = \frac{2^n-6}{2^n}$ (for $n \geq 3$ otherwise it is zero) and then the expected value for the necessary number of bits is $$3+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} 1-T(n) = 4.5$$ this is not an improvement in comparison to NcAdams solution which needs $\frac{8}{7}*3 \approx 3.42$ bits. (the main culprit is that after 3 bits this method has only a decision for 25% of the cases)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by AdamO's answer, here is a Python solution that avoids bias:

```
def roll(p, n):
    remaining = range(1,n+1)
    flips = 0
    while len(remaining) > 1:
        round_winners = [c for c in remaining if random.choices(['H','T'], [p, 1.0-p]) == ['H']]
        flips += len(remaining)
        if len(round_winners) > 0:
            remaining = round_winners
        p = 1.0 - p
    return remaining[0], flips
```

There are two main changes here: The main one is that if all the number are discarded in a round, repeat the round. Also I flip the choice of whether heads or tails means discard every time. This reduces the number of flips needed in cases where p is close to 0 or 1 by ~70% when p=0.999

Comment: "I flip the choice of whether heads or tails means discard every time. This reduces the number of flips needed in cases where p is close to 0 or 1 by ~70% when p=0.999" - smart thinking!

Comment: Alternating heads or tails is definitely an improvement over always discarding heads -- but perhaps it would be better if, after flipping a coin for each remaining option, if they are all the same we repeat reflipping all of them, otherwise if there are at least as many heads as tails we eliminate the remaining options corresponding to heads, otherwise we eliminate the remaining options corresponding to tails.

Answer (score 2):

It appears **we are allowed to change the mapping of the outcome of each flip, every time we flip**. So, using for convenience the first seven positive integers, we give the following orders:

1st Flip,  map $H \to 1$
2nd Flip,  map $H \to 2$
...
7th flip, map $H \to 7$
8th flip, map $H \to 1$

etc

Repeat, always in batches of 7 flips. Map the $T$ outcomes to nothing.

**SOME REMARKS ON EFFICIENCY**
Our RNG, index it by $AP$, will generate zero useful outcomes in one 7-flip batch if we get $T$ in all 7 flips. So

$$P_{AP}(\text{no integers generated}) = (1-p)^7$$

As we run $N_b$ 7-flip batches, the total number of useless flips will tend to

$$\text{Count}_{AP}(\text{useless flips}) \to 7\cdot N_b(1-p)^7$$

**Consider now  the RNG of @DilipSarwate.** There, we use a binomial $B(p,n=5)$ and 5-flip batches. The seven outcomes that generate an integer each has probability of occuring $p^3(1-p)^2$, so, in a 5-flip batch

$$P_{DS}(\text{no integers generated}) = 1-7\cdot p^3(1-p)^2$$

The count of useless flips will here tend to

$$\text{Count}_{DS}(\text{useless flips}) \to 5\cdot N_b\cdot [1-7\cdot p^3(1-p)^2]$$

For the $AP$ RNG to tend to produce less useless flips, it must be the case that

$$ \text{Count}_{AP}(\text{useless flips}) < \text{Count}_{DS}(\text{useless flips})$$

$$\implies  7\cdot N_b(1-p)^7 < 5\cdot N_b\cdot [1-7\cdot p^3(1-p)^2]$$

$$\implies  7\cdot (1-p)^7 < 5\cdot [1-7\cdot p^3(1-p)^2]$$

Numerical examination shows that if $p>0.0467$, then the $AP$ RNG generates less useless flips.

We also find that the number of useless flips is monotonically decreasing in $p$ for the $AP$ RNG, while for the $DS$ RNG it has a minimum at around $p\approx 0.5967$ and then increases again, while in general it stays high. The ratio

$$\frac{\text{Count}_{AP}(\text{useless flips})}{\text{Count}_{DS}(\text{useless flips})}$$

declines pretty quickly. For example it is equal to $0.67$ for$p=0.1$, equal to $0.3$ for $p=0.2$, equal to $0.127$ for $p=0.4$.

Comment: Suppose we want to minimize the total number of flips required to generate an integer. I think that your answer provides the minimum total flips across all $p\in(0,1)$. Can you elaborate on that point?

Comment: @Sycorax I added something, although I am not sure it is along the lines you suggested.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Why? if we get all $H$, we will get each integer once. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I believe this is another "trick" answer: the question doesn't specify that the integers must be generated at random.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings What is special about this possible sequence, compared to, say, {1,T,3,4,T,6,7}?

Comment: @Sycorax Eventually, we will get a sequence containing the required integers, where each _element_ of the sequence has been generated independently from all the others, and each with equal probability. Moreover each integer will be present with approx the same relative frequency. The "trick" here is about changing the random variable in each one of the seven flips. Each flip in a 7-flip batch is not the same random variable, but a different one.

Comment: @Sycorax The issue is, does the generated sequence mimic the properties of an i.i.d. sequence of Discrete Uniforms ranging in {1,2,...,7}? That is the goal here.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos your efficiency is much higher than you calculation. You compare the number of useless flips, but you generate relatively many more random numbers per flip.

Comment: If you go into this interpretation of (extremely pseudo) "random"-number generator, as just any sequence with equal amount of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, then you can just as well not flip any coin and directly take the sequence of digits in the number $\frac{1234567}{9999999}$.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Martin, if I cannot distinguish my sequence from an i.i.d. sequence of Uniforms, then it is a perfectly fine RNG, and whether it is in principle, extremely or moderately "pseudo" has no consequence whatsoever. The interesting task with the various proposed algorithms here would be for them to be hard-tested with the battery of tests that have been devised to assess how well "randomness" is mimicked.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, to me the principle should be that we could perform, at any moment, a fair coin-toss among 7 instead of 2 people, when we have the availability of a coin with both head and tails a non-zero probability. But certainly you can stretch such interpretation (especially given the ambiguity in the question), although that is a different type of discussion.

Comment: *"The issue is, does the generated sequence mimic the properties of an i.i.d. sequence of Discrete Uniforms ranging in {1,2,...,7}?"* The generated sequence clearly contains the 7 digits with equal probability, so I think this is a valuable contribution, but (even if the coin tosses themselves are independent, and even if the coin is fair!) won't the stream of digits produced fail any test of independence?

Comment: @Silverfish To put it simply, I don't know, I haven't thought it through. And I am not really familiar with the suites of independence tests used to test the validity of RNGs.

Comment: You can use independence test, for statistical/experimental verification.... but we already know, based on the theoretical knowledge how the random number is generated, that the numbers are not independent. We can calculate exact probabilities for certain subsequences.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings All sequences coming from deterministic RNG's are somehow dependent, this is not the issue here. The question is, which aspects of "randomness" are we after? If we just want a pool of numbers where each integer has the same relative frequency, then my algorithm works. But what about other facets of "randomness"? If we examine spacings inbetween the appearance of the same integer, then the distribution of them is different than from an i.i.d. Uniform (I simulated it, but it should be expected). So if we want to maintain the order of draws, this algorithm fails.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos a coin is not a deterministic RNG. The key question is how to get from two unfair states to seven fair states. Turning it into a different type of random number generator is a different type of discussion (almost semantic, 'what did the OP mean?') and if you go down that path then you can just as well discard the coin (and use R, or as I suggest use the digits from $\frac{1234567}{9999999}$) as some of the answers have suggested.

Comment: By the way, I agree that it is a fun and original solution. But it is a bit useless to discuss the randomness and what tests to use to verify the "randomness" while it is clear that the procedure introduces a bias regarding the order in which the numbers occur (also the efficiency seems a bit useless to test if you have a completely different type of RNG).

Comment: This obviously devastates the efficiency, but it might help to distinguish between the stream of numbers the coin generates by this procedure, and the stream we actually choose to output. For example, I think the first number in the outputted stream would be much closer to uniform if there was a "burn-in" period and the first $N$ numbers generated were ignored ($N$ would need to be higher if $P(heads)$ were near 1) and I believe the output stream would behave rather closer to independence if we threw away $N$ generated numbers after each one we outputted.

Comment: For a short experiment in R try `n<-1e6; prob<-0.9; keep<-7000; gen<-((cumsum(1+rgeom(n,prob))-1)%%7)+1; gen[1:20]; out<-gen[keep*(1:(n/keep))]; out[1:20]` displays the generated digits then the output after discarding all but every `keep`th. I chose a `keep` divisible by 7 so that effects of modular arithmetic are more obvious and less likely to be mistaken for randomness (try setting `prob<-0.99998` instead!). If it is known which of $P(heads)$ and $P(tails)$ is smaller, mapping the more likely one to nothing has some desirable properties, e.g. makes runs of consecutive numbers less likely.

Comment: This sequence can clearly be distinguished from a sequence of i.i.d uniforms on {1..7}. For all but one specific value of $p$, the probability that the first value will be 1 is not $\frac{1}{7}$. For any value of $p$, the event that the second value is 2 will not be independent of the event that the first value is 1. A sequence which has, on average, an equal number of each value, is a much much weaker condition that i.i.d uniforms. Eg., a sequence where I choose a number fairly and repeat it a million times, satisfies the first condition (and is much more 'efficient' than this answer).

Comment: @jwg Indeed, that's true. In general, the spacings between observing the same number do not follow a geometric distribution with $p=1/7$ as they should if the sequence was discrete Uniform(1,7) i.i.d. What this algorithm does is to produce a non-ordered pool of the seven integers having equal empirical frequencies, and so equal probabilities to be drawn. If the sequence-order needs to be preserved, the algorithm does not deliver. The question is how many other algorithms proposed in this thread have the same issue.

Comment: *"The question is how many other algorithms proposed in this thread have the same issue. "* most algorithms in this thread provide i.i.d. Uniform(1,7) if the coin flips are i.i.d Bernoulli(p).

Comment: Your method does obtains the property 'every number 1...7 equal represented' independent of the coin flips (it has not much to do with it), but it obtains this by the fact that you use a sequence 12345671234567etc. The only random thing that you do with this method is randomly eliminating the numbers from that sequence (so there is *some* randomness), but *without* this step you just as well have a sequence of numbers with equal proportions of numbers between 1 and 7. Thus, the coin flips are useless.